# Platform java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.String> (with no annotations) requires explicit JsonAdapter to be registered android

Tags: java, android, json, moshi

I'm trying to convert a JSON string to Java Object using the Moshi library for Android. The object contains a property of type

```
ArrayList<String>
```

After app run, throws following exception

```
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Platform java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.String> (with no annotations) requires explicit JsonAdapter to be registered
for java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.String> result
for class com.xxxx.data.remote.response.NewsResponse
    at com.squareup.moshi.Moshi$LookupChain.exceptionWithLookupStack(Moshi.java:348)
    at com.squareup.moshi.Moshi.adapter(Moshi.java:149)
    at com.squareup.moshi.ClassJsonAdapter$1.createFieldBindings(ClassJsonAdapter.java:99)
    at com.squareup.moshi.ClassJsonAdapter$1.create(ClassJsonAdapter.java:82)
    at com.squareup.moshi.Moshi.adapter(Moshi.java:137)
    at com.squareup.moshi.Moshi.adapter(Moshi.java:97)
    at retrofit2.converter.moshi.MoshiConverterFactory.responseBodyConverter(MoshiConverterFactory.java:91)
    at retrofit2.Retrofit.nextResponseBodyConverter(Retrofit.java:362)
    at retrofit2.Retrofit.responseBodyConverter(Retrofit.java:345)
    at retrofit2.HttpServiceMethod.createResponseConverter(HttpServiceMethod.java:124)
```

Comment: Use List<String>

Comment: Use MutableList<String>

Answer (score 3):

Even I've faced the same issue.

After hours of searching, found the solution by Eric helpful.

Using List instead of ArrayList solved the issue.